# Create a database in sql*plus (sql command line)

Tags: sql, oracle

I've used mysql shell for creating database (create database testdb), why can't i make a database in sql*plus command line. I also want to see the lists of database but i can't find queries anywhere. Please guide

```
SQL> create database testdb;
create database testdb
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed
ORA-01100: database already mounted


SQL>
```

Comment: sqlplus is for orcale not for mysql

Comment: you already have a database.  Don't confuse data with schema in oracle.  Read [Oracle Database Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/index.html)

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are different database management systems, like [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) and [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/products/db2-database?p1=Search&p4=43700052307240256&p5=e&cm_mmc=Search_Google-_-1S_1S-_-EP_IL-_-db2_e&cm_mmca7=71700000064658944&cm_mmca8=aud-309367918490:kwd-11399081&cm_mmca9=EAIaIQobChMIjtLJvuTZ6gIVlIjVCh01gQIFEAAYASAEEgJ1JfD_BwE&cm_mmca10=449270192368&cm_mmca11=e&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjtLJvuTZ6gIVlIjVCh01gQIFEAAYASAEEgJ1JfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). _SQL*Plus_ is for use with Oracle only. What database are you using?

Comment: Which database do you try to connect to ? MySql or Oracle ? Use command SELECT NAME FROM v$database; for oracle database. Use command show databases; for MySql. This two command will show you the list of all databases;

Comment: I'm really sorry if I'm trying something dump. I wanted to make a project for my university just a simple database on which i can run queries like SELECT * from users; My teacher guided me to install oracal 10g she also sent us a file of SQL type( sampledb.sql) we practiced our queries with that file some tables were already there. Now for project i used MYSQL because this SQL command line was showing this error. I just wanted to ask how can i create a new database in that sqlplus command line, Sorry I'm so confused.

Comment: @AsadUllahShahid You probably just want to create a user with a command like `create user some_user identified by "some_password";` That user will need privileges, and if this is an unimportant sandbox database you *may* be able to ignore security and just run `grant dba to some_user;`

Comment: "My teacher guided me to install oracal 10g ".  That's not very encouraging, seeing as oracle 10g is completely obsolete. It has been superseded by 11.1, then 11.2, then12.1, then 12.2, then 18, then 19 .....

Comment: Please read the following (at "dummies.com", but please don't be insulted by the site name (I dislike all the "<X> for Dummies" and "<Y> for Dummies" books, but I'm old and think I should be treated as an intelligent person (*sigh*) ): [Basic Definitions of Databases and Instances In Oracle 12c](https://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/basic-definitions-of-databases-and-instances-in-oracle-12c/). Although you're using 10g the information is still helpful. As others have said, in Oracle terms I think you want to create a "user" and its related "schema" rather than a database.